# Does Google handle featured images as duplicate content?

Tags: google, images, seo

I own a photography website and for each post I attach a featured image that is exactly like the original one but much smaller. Does Google count the featured image as duplicate content?

Comment: No. Otherwise, in general duplicate content is about texts, not images.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

It’s very common to have the *same* image on several different pages. And you even don’t have the (technically) same image in the first place, because it’s a thumbnail.

(However, to be really sure, you’d better include an example in your question.)